# Where is an Orchard Core Detail Template Displayed vs an Orchard Summary Template?

Tags: orchardcore

I have created in a Widget in Orchard Core to display a different image in the list every 30 minutes.  I have replaced the detail template and it seems to work fine in a Page Content Type.  There is also a Summary Template.  What is that for and where is it displayed?

Here is my liquid code to display the image:

```
{%- assign imageIndex = 0 -%}
{%- assign max = Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.ImageRotatorImages.Paths.size -%}
{%- assign minute = "now" | date: "%M" | plus: 0 -%}
{%- if minute <= 30 -%}
    {%- assign target = "now" | date: "%H" | plus: 0 -%}
{%- else -%}
    {%- assign target = "now" | date: "%H" | plus: 23 -%}
{%- endif  -%}
{%- for i in (0..48) -%}
    {%- if i == target -%}
        <img src="{{Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.ImageRotatorImages.Paths[imageIndex] | asset_url}}"
          {% if Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.AltText and Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.AltText.Text.size > 0 -%} alt="{{Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.AltText.Text}}"{%- endif -%}
          {%- if Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.ID and Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.ID.Text.size > 0 -%} id="{{Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.ID.Text}}"{%- endif -%}
          {%- if Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Class and  Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Class.Text.size > 0 -%} class="{{Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Class.Text}}"{%- endif -%}
          {%- if Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Height and Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Height.Text.size > 0 -%} height="{{Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Height.Text}}"{%- endif -%}
          {%- if Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Width and  Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Width.Text.size > 0 -%} width="{{Model.ContentItem.Content.ImageRotator.Width.Text}}"{%- endif %}
             >
        {%- break -%}
    {%- endif -%}

    {%- assign imageIndex = imageIndex | plus: 1 -%}

    {%- if imageIndex >= max -%}
        {%- assign imageIndex = 0 -%}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As stated in docs](https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/latest/docs/reference/modules/Themes/#display-types):

Detail display type is used when rendering the whole content item, for example, a Blog post site.

Summary display type is used when rendering multiple items at once in a list, rendering item only partially, for example, last 10 Blog posts in a blog, you'll probably want to render the only title and short intro, not the whole article

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The link for the documentation page is broken.